# Unknown column error when trying to add data to table in mysql database in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I get this error when adding data to the database.
How do I solve this?

Error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'hn' in 'field list'

I know this column does not exist but I am not sending data to such a column anyway.

My Python code:

```
def addToTable(table_name,connection,column_name_list,*data_list):
 
    if(len(column_name_list) != len(data_list)):
        raise ValueError("'column_name_list' length has to be equal to 'data_list' length. Please check the parameters")
    cursor = connection.cursor()  # initializing a cursor
    for column_data in range(len(data_list[0])):
        addList = list()
        for data in range(len(data_list)):
            added = str(data_list[data][column_data])
            addList.append(added)
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " VALUES (" + ", ".join(str(k) for k in addList) + ")")
        mydb.commit()
        print("Added {} in {} ...".format(added, table_name))
```

Sample query sent from python code:

`INSERT INTO deneme VALUES (hn, 1212, asdmailcom)`

calling the function:

```
names = ["hn","ben","alex",]
numbers = [1212,1245,54541]
mails = ["asdmailcom","fghmailcom","xyzmailcom"]

columns = ["de","ne","me"]

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1",
                                   user="root",
                                   passwd="1234",
                                   database="deneme",
                                   auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')

addToTable("deneme",mydb,columns,names,numbers,mails)
```

My table name is 'deneme', database name is 'deneme'. Columns : 'de' varchar(45), 'ne' varchar(45), 'me' varchar(45)

Comment: But hn is not in the columns,but instead is in names list.

Comment: Yes i don't understand this.

Comment: your insert is somehow wrong i `INSERT INTO deneme VALUES (hn, 1212, asdmailcom)`
it should be `Insert Into TableName (column1, column2, column3, ...)VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...)`

Comment: does this help?

Comment: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " ("+ ",".join(x for x in column_name_list) +") VALUES (" + ", ".join(str(k) for k in addList) + ")")`

query of this code : 
INSERT INTO deneme (de,ne,me) VALUES (hn, 1212, asdmailcom)

But i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I explained in the comment lines.

```
def addToTable(table_name,connection,column_name_list,*data_list):
    if(len(column_name_list) != len(data_list)):       
        raise ValueError("'column_name_list' length has to be equal to 'data_list' length. Please check the parameters")

    cursor = connection.cursor()  # initializing a cursor
    for column_data in range(len(data_list[0])):
        addList = list()
        for data in range(len(data_list)):
            added = str(data_list[data][column_data])
            added = "'"+added+"'" # the purpose of this line is to convert the data to string
                                  # example: without this line
                                  #          query ---> INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (lorem,ipsum,sit)
                                  # example: with this line
                                  #          query ---> INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, ...) VALUES ('lorem','ipsum','sit')
            addList.append(added)
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " VALUES (" + ", ".join(str(k) for k in addList) + ")")
        mydb.commit()
        print("Added {} in {} ...".format(added, table_name))
```